# Как лучше оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Сейчас рано делать выводы и заключения о масштабах нашего будущего производства, но одно могу сказать точно, прогноз такой: оно будет только расти.

Можно ли оформить как-то по-другому? (Т.к. двоеточие напрашивается уже после слов "могу сказать точно")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант: Сейчас рано делать выводы и заключения о масштабах нашего будущего производства, но одно могу сказать точно: по (всем)прогнозам оно будет только расти.

Прогноз - научное предсказание хода и результатов каких-л. событий, мероприятий, процессов.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я Вам очень благодарна. И даже не знаю, чем могу отблагодарить. Вы мне очень помогаете.

Comment: Аленка, Вы нам тоже помогаете, присылая вопросы. При решении различных задач знания проверяются на практике, что приносит несомненную пользу отвечающим. А заданий по грамматике здесь не так много.